# Excel linking to page from Quickbooks

Tags: excel, report, quickbooks

I'm getting a weird error when linking to a cell in another sheet in the same excel workbook when the linked sheet was exported from Quickbooks.  This actually also happens when linking inside the same sheet.

I can link to anything 1 time and it will display the linked text as expected.  I can then overwrite that cell with a new link to a number or date and it will work.  But if I overwrite the cell with a new link to an alpha / text string, it only displays the formula (i.e. =Sheet1!C93.)

Things I've tried:
Cutting / pasting the QB text
Changing text type to general, number, etc.
Linking in the same sheet (also causes the error.)
Saving the xls as macro-enabled

UPDATE:
While trying more things, I found the solution.  I am only continuing with the post because I couldn't find the solution with a search and would like to post in case someone else has this issue.  Feel free to add any reasoning for why this might be.  I'm guessing QB puts some weird formatting into their alpha text.  Sorry if the solution seems a bit basic.

SOLUTION:
Copy and paste the QB report as Values.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Copy and paste the QB report as Values.

Comment: Scratch that solution.  It worked for a while then stopped working.  The next thing that is working is to also change the number type to General.